# Commits made after a Pull Request is created are not captured during merge

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

Steps to Reproduce:

- Created feature branch
- Made changes
- Created Pull Request (with minimum 1 Approval required)
- Reviewer gives approval
- Pushed new change to branch after noticing typo
- This late change is not merged down with of the code

Normally I have no trouble adding new changes to code after creating a Pull Request.  I assume that in this case the late change did not merge because approval had already been given, but that approval did not cover the late change.  I've looked through Atlassian's documentation but can find nothing to confirm this theory.  Can anyone confirm or reject this theory?  It would be handy to know what steps to avoid in future.

Thanks.

Comment: no that shouldn't be the problem. i also did that a few times after my kolleagues approved and it merged correctly. maybe you were on the wrong branch/ merged already the pull request/ had connection issues?

Comment: OK, thanks for the reply.  That sounds like it should be the correct workflow, but just wanted to see if anybody else had come across the same issue.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ex-Stash developer here. That's absolutely not expected, and either sounds like a bug or, as Florian suggested, you have pushed to the wrong branch or something else.

If you are still seeing this behaviour then please feel free to contact Atlassian's support:

https://support.atlassian.com